# Is there a way to use MSBuild version 12 in github actions with github-hosted runners?

Tags: msbuild, github-actions

tried using this in the workflow steps

run: |
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\Bin\"

.\msbuild.exe

but it says it is not found in this location?

Comment: https://blog.lextudio.com/the-rough-history-of-msbuild-cc72a217fa98 MSBuild 12 is part of VS2013, so if you don't install that explicitly on an agent machine, it won't be there.